# Insert PNG Image via Button Userform VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with a button that will prompt the user to upload an image, everything works perfectly. However, when I try to upload in `.png` format it gives the error message `Invalid Picture`. I'm assuming that it does not allow `.png` format... Is there any work around for this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Add "Image", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            ' file has been selected

            ' e.g. show path in textbox
            Me.TextBox1.Text = .SelectedItems(1)

            ' e.g. display preview image in an image control
            Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
            Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
        Else
            ' user aborted the dialog

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry got trigger happen when I posted... I've got my code there now

Comment: I just confirmed that `png` is not supported for that control. You would have to convert it to something like `jpg` first, which should be possible in VBA. Have a look around for that code.

Comment: Are you aware of any work around? I don't mind something I can use to convert the image if possible too

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.devhut.net/2017/05/14/vba-wia-convert-the-image-format/

Comment: Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23672244/2877364).  @braX LoadPicture is a built-in, not a user routine.

Comment: @cxw Thanks, I don't work much with images in VBA. VB.NET makes it so much easier.

Comment: I am voting to close as duplicate, since the issue here seems to be the loading of the PNG, and not what happens to it afterwards.  The linked Q (as far as I can tell) has PNG-loading covered.  (However, I haven't tested anything. :) )

Comment: And [another Google result](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26980514/VBA-LoadPicture-with-PNG-files.html#a35498853) from That Other Q&A Site.  **Edit** Plus [one from MrExcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/691847-using-png-images-userform.html).  OK - enough from me!  Good luck!

Comment: @Maldred - with all the interest you seem to have in learning all these things recently, I recommend you try out VB.NET by getting Visual Studio 2017 (it's free, and SO MUCH BETTER)

Comment: @cxw Thanks for all your suggestions! I managed to get it working with the last one you mentioned!

Comment: @braX Unfortunately, I am unable to install any software on my workstation computer, but this is definitely something I will look into at home, thanks for the recommendation

Comment: @Maldred Glad to be able to help!